# How to install newer vala compiler?

Tags: vala

I'm trying to contribute to Granite, but I'm still on elementary OS v5, which doesn't include the required vala computed version.

Thanks to jeremypw I found the relevant ppa:
[https://launchpad.net/~vala-team/+archive/ubuntu/next](https://launchpad.net/%7Evala-team/+archive/ubuntu/next)

I installed the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team/next 
sudo apt-get update
```

But then I struggled knowing what to install. `valac` itself was still at 0.40:

```
valac/bionic,now 0.40.25-0ubuntu1~18.04~valateam0 amd64 [installed]
  C# like language for the GObject system
```

I did find valac-bin:

```
valac-bin/bionic,now 0.52.2-0ubuntu1~18.04~valateam0 amd64 [installed]
  internal package for C# like language for the GObject system
```

After installing things look good:

```
valac --version
Vala 0.52.2
```

But when running meson I'm now getting this error:

```
meson build --prefix=/usr 
The Meson build system
Version: 0.49.2
Source dir: /home/peteruithoven/Projects/elementary/granite
Build dir: /home/peteruithoven/Projects/elementary/granite/build
Build type: native build
Project name: granite
Project version: 6.1.0
Native C compiler: cc (gcc 7.5.0 "cc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0")

meson.build:1:0: ERROR:  Vala compiler 'valac' can not compile programs

A full log can be found at /home/peteruithoven/Projects/elementary/granite/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

Comment: I think you need to install the matching valac-0.52-vapi package as well

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer, that way I can indicate it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the matching vapi package (valac-0.52-vapi) as well the compiler binary (valac-bin).